# Как закруглить края кнопки в Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qpushbutton

Не могу закруглить кнопку и поле ввода в *Qt Designer*. Уже пробовал записывать `border-radius` в файл стилей, но это не помогает а больше способов не знаю, через код это делать не хочется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>0</width>
    <height>0</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
   <enum>Qt::NoContextMenu</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="acceptDrops">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Вычисление BMI</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="background">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>801</width>
      <height>601</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="pixmap">
     <pixmap>background.png</pixmap>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="heigth">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>280</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>401</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>17</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Введите свой рост:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="main_text">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>210</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>391</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Myanmar Text</family>
      <pointsize>35</pointsize>
      <weight>50</weight>
      <italic>false</italic>
      <bold>false</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font: 35pt &quot;Myanmar Text&quot;;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Вычисление BMI</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="input_heigth">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>331</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border-radius: 100;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="weigth">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>280</x>
      <y>240</y>
      <width>401</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>17</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Введите свой вес:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="input_weigth">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>300</y>
      <width>331</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="answer">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>290</x>
      <y>370</y>
      <width>211</width>
      <height>41</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="cursor">
     <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(120, 183, 140);
border-radius: 25px;
border: 2px solid #094065;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Узнать BMI</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="input_weigth_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>230</x>
      <y>460</y>
      <width>331</width>
      <height>31</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: пожалуйста опубликуйте ваш модуль `.ui`

Comment: нужен именно код с файла .ui?

Comment: то что вы показали на изображение, надо сохранить в  Qt Designer. Например с  именем `q1391783.ui`, а потом содержимое этого модуля опубликуйте в теле вопроса.

Comment: добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(120, 183, 140);
border-radius: 20px;                     /* <----  20px  */ 
border: 2px solid #094065;
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ЗахарУляшов пожалуйста.

Comment: Есть еще вопрос) Как сделать так что-бы при вводе текста в LineEdit он отображался посередине, а не слева. text-align уже пробовал, не помогает)

Comment: @ЗахарУляшов если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.